# How to make NSTableView stop alternating rows on bottom?

Tags: macos, nstableview

I am new to macOS development, and I'd like to have my `NSTableView` rows alternate, but it looks quite ugly at the bottom where there are no more cells. The cells still alternate, but they're smaller than the rows I have, and thus look wrong.

I'd like the alternating rows to stop alternating at the bottom, but I can't seem to find information on how to do that. How can I stop the alternating rows at the bottom?

What it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Could you share a screen shot? Also, did you expect all rows to be the same size? How are you setting the size of each row?

Comment: @Ron edited to include a screenshot

Comment: Switch off Alternating Rows and draw backgrounds in the rows or cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps set the default row height to the height of your filled-in cells?

In IB, or programmatically like so:

```
       tableView.rowSizeStyle = .custom
       tableView.rowHeight = the height of your cell
```